# Microsoft Graph API: Filter messages received last month

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I was wondering if Microsoft Graph has filtering available to retrieve emails only received last month that is from 1st day of last month to last day of last month.
Also, I save custom user properties with each email called "CompletedTime". I would also like to know if there is any filtering which would only pull emails which has value in custom user property "CompletedTime".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KQL has a reserved keyword for last month https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference so something like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="received:\"last month\""&$select=subject,receivedDateTime&$Top=1000
```

Should work to return the last months email, you could also do a filter or a search using a date range.

> Also, I save custom user properties with each email called "CompletedTime". I would also like to know if there is any filtering which would only pull emails which has value in custom user property "CompletedTime".

If you know what the extended property representation of the property is then you can use a Filter on that. (If you don't know what the extended property is then use a MAPI editor like OutlookSpy of mfcmapi to work it out.

Comment: Thank you very much Glen. Much appreciated.